# Magento 2 I get order with increment id in previous none used auto increment id

Tags: mysql, magento, magento2

I have order with increment id '000005104' and the next id is '000003931' and the next id is '000005006'
I am asking for how to prevent it, I want to keep the sequence continues of order increment ids.
Also, I need to know this behavior is the default or I have a problem?

Comment: You need to explain a bit more about your problem, and what you are trying to achieve. Maybe show the whole sql command, and what you would like that command to achieve.

Comment: @Sourcery  I am asking for how to prevent it, I want to keep the sequence continues of order increment ids. Also, I need to know this behavior is the default or I have a problem?

Comment: As Hariharasubramaniam says in an answer below the normal step value is 1. I still would like you to show the sql command and what you would like to get out of that command. It could be as simple as an order issue?

Answer (score 0):

By default Magento's Order Increment id have a step value of 1

Assuming you have access to your site's database, If you wish to change that or see what is current step value, check it on this table.

> **sales_sequence_profile**

If the step value is not 1 , your order increment ids will be not in sequence
To get sequential values edit this value

Hope this helps!